# FULLTEXT MATCH AGAINST in a VARCHAR column using an integer

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, magento2

I have the following query which give me one result :

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (MATCH(`main_table`.increment_id) 
AGAINST('BC0000257891'))
```

The increment ids are formatted like that : "AB-BC0000123456" and the result will be one row, that is perfect, we found the order.
However, if my search is only "257891" or even "0000257891", it won't return the row.

My question is : how can I find this row in this example ?
I tried to add quotes and it didn't work `AGAINST('"0000257891"'))`

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *how can I find this row in this example ?* Noway. Fulltext is not applicable for searching by a substring. If your criteria is always a tail substring then I recommend to add generated column (if MySQL version allows - virtual) with reversed `increment_id` and index it, and perform selection by reversed criteria using common LIKE.

Comment: _Fulltext is not applicable for searching by a substring_. But "BC0000257891" is actually a substring of "AB-BC0000257891" no ? Do you think "BC0000257891" has been indexed ?

Comment: Store FTS only for a chance that full code will be entered? This is not rational...